# Jquery new Date giving wrong data when passing to yyyy dd mm

Tags: jquery, date, format

I am using remote desktop and there i am using below code in my javascript file

```
var birthday = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
  console.log(birthday);
```

but the output is coming like this :-

```
Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time).
```

I was expecting Sun Jab 01 2017.

RDP is hosted in UK . Is there something i am doing wrong  ?

Comment: in `Date`, months are zero-based: `new Date(2017, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The `month` in the `Date` object of javascript is 0-based, so [month 1 is actually February](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (**note that the month is 0-based**). Similarly for other values: new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70) is equivalent to new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10) which both create a date for 2013-03-01T01:10:00.

It's also the same for the [`getMonth` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth):

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Comment: So how to fix to get the correct date if we have to pass dd mm yyyy as a parameter

Comment: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.  .. This can help

Comment: If Jan is 0 and Feb is 1, and you want Jan, just use 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
];

var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(day, monthNames[monthIndex], year);
```

// Output:  17 January 2017